# Spring - how to change property

Tags: spring

I have a class which I can't change:

```
public class A {
  private String amountOfErrors;

  public String getAmountOfErrors() {
    return amountOfErrors;
  }

  public void setAmountOfErrors(String amountOfErrors) {
    this.amountOfErrors = amountOfErrors;
  }
}
```

bean which I can change:

```
<bean class="com.company.facades.A">
  <property name="amountOfErrors" type="String"/>
</bean>
```

How can I change a type String to BigDecimal to call smth like that:

```
 A a = new A();
 a.setAmountOfErrors(BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

Comment: no you cannot, maybe you can try like this `a.setAmountOfErrors(BigDecimal.ZERO.toString()`

Comment: @Deadpool What if I added <property name="bigAmountOfErrors" type="BigDecimal"/>?

Comment: you will get error during startup saying incompatible types

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, true. And I need to extend class A with field bigAmountOfErrors. Maybe you know a mechanism to do this using spring?

Comment: Hi!  Then why not just do that? - you wouldn't even need to change the method name.  You could just provide a version of the method with the same name but that takes a BigDecimal.  Is it that you can't write ANY new Java code?

Comment: @Steve Maybe you know a mechanism to do this using spring? How to provide a version of the method?

Comment: See my answer.  Tell me more if this doesn't seem like what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends somewhat on how you're injecting the bean.  But basically just:

```
public class B extends A {
  public void setAmountOfErrors(BigDecimal amountOfErrors) {
    this.amountOfErrors = amountOfErrors.toString();
  }
}

<bean class="com.company.whatever.B">
  <property name="amountOfErrors" type="BigDecimal"/>
</bean>
```

I'm actually not sure what you're trying to do with the property on either A or B.  The main point is that you can create a B, but Spring will know it's an A and will inject it as an A where necessary.

But if you want to call the BigDecimal version of the setter from Java, you'll need to either inject it as a B or cast an injected A (that's really a B) to a B.

Comment: Does this make sense?  What more can I do to try to help?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I didn't think much about your line: **<property name="amountOfErrors" type="String"/>**.  Thinking about it more, I realized that I didn't know the purpose of this line, and I don't think I've ever used one quite like this in my 10+ years of using Spring.  I've used the 'value' and 'ref' attributes, but never 'type'.  What do you think the purpose of this is?  I'm not saying I know it has no purpose.  I just can't think what that purpose is.  Maybe you can teach me something :) - I also did some Googling, and couldn't find such a usage.